# Advantage of C++20 modules over precompiled headers for compiling speed?

Tags: c++, c++20, precompiled, c++-modules

C++20's module feature is supposed to improve compile speed. But what is the advantage over precompiled headers, which also makes it fast to include a library?

Comment: That is far too dependent on various factors (most importantly, quality of implementations in a period of time when modules are still new) to be able to answer.

Comment: One possible advantage is the isolation you get with modules. You only export what you explicitly said (in the module implementation) that should be exported.